# does contain and does not contain in same if

Tags: c#

For some reason i cannot get this if statement to work

```
if (htmlCode.Contains("Sign out") && !htmlCode.Contains("bye bye")) 
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

is there any way to get contains and does not contain to work in same if statement?

Comment: what's not working ? please post the error you are getting ...

Comment: What exactly "does not work"? Program crash? ??

Comment: `&&` should be replaced with `||`.

Comment: @Lion Is there an indication that that is what he wants? The code should work as is.

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work - the htmlCode contains the "Sign out " and doesn't contain "bye bye" and it and the code in the if clause is not running?

Comment: its strange because Sign out is on the page and bye bye is not but its still not // do stuff

Comment: I have seen people report these types of problems when they forget that case matters when doing string compares.  You could try toUpper() on the htmlCode string and compare it to uppercase strings.

Comment: @alexy12, are you sure the HTML markup is `bye bye` and not something like `bye&nbsp;bye`?

Comment: Adding to what @Frédéric Hamidi commented, the rendered text may be "bye bye", but since whitespace is not significant in HTML it's possible that there's more than one space between the two words, or that they're separated by a tab, newline, or some other whitespace characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all check the htmlCode, the text could be mixed with some html tags or something like that, also the issue can be with cases, when trying to find some string in the text you should always remember about cases.

You can use `.Contains` method or `.IndexOf`, actually the contains method in the Framework is implemented like this:

```
public bool Contains(string value)
{
  return this.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0;
}
```

For comparing large strings without knowing the case I would use:

```
htmlCode.IndexOf("Sign out", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
htmlCode.IndexOf("Bye bye", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

If you know that response will be small, you can use `.ToLower()` or `.ToUpper()`

Answer (score 1):

Try to compare by converting either upper case or lower case.

```
if (htmlCode.ToUpper().Contains("SIGN OUT") && !htmlCode.ToUpper().Contains("BYE BYE")) 
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

Comment: you beat on my time and suggest upper and i suggested lower

Comment: @HatSoft, [CA1308: Normalize strings to uppercase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386042.aspx).

Comment: @HatSoft: :D. Its just the logic that before we compare we should convert to fixed case in order to avoid mistake.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Useful link, deserves +1.

Answer (score 1):

You if clause works correctly

It might be not working because of the string case

So i would suggest you do it this way

```
if (htmlCode.ToUpper().Contains("Sign out".ToUpper()) && !htmlCode.ToUpper().Contains("bye bye".ToUpper()))
```